# How to exclude classes that are added using Spring's AutoConfiguration when using @WebMvcTest?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I want to test my Controller using `@WebMvcTest` and mock the dependencies, but Spring Boot's AutoConfiguration loads my Couchbase (Spring Data) configuration automatically. Couchbase is not available on some platforms which run the test, so the Test class will throw an Exception. How can I exclude some classes from the AutoConfiguration mechanism?

I tried the `excludeFilters` option of `@WebMvcTest` and `@ActiveProfile` to load another Application Context, but that didn't work.

Test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ExchangeJobImportController.class, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(classes = CouchbaseConfiguration.class))
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ExchangeJobImportControllerTest {
  ...
}
```

Couchbase Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseAuditing
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CouchbaseProperties.class})
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = "com....")
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more struggling I found the solution: exclude the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the `@WebMvcTest` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ExchangeJobImportController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = Application.class, secure = false)
@ActiveProfiles("localhost")
public class ExchangeJobImportControllerTest {
  ...
}
```

For the record, I am using Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: Struggle to find this configuration for a Filter that fail for one hour!! Thank you!

Comment: FYI: I'm using Spring boot 3.1.0 and the `secure` flag doesn't exist anymore, it was removed but i don't know exactly since which version

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been some time but I suppose the reason why the `@ComponentScan.Filter` solution doesn't work is that it looks for an annotation type for the `classes` field by default.

So, setting the `FilterType` as `ASSIGNABLE_TYPE` should work in your case:

```java
@ComponentScan.Filter(
    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
    classes = CouchbaseConfiguration.class
)
```